# Finding out if multiple values in a list of lists are the same value

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my problem:

I have a list of lists (adjoining) that is setup of x and y coordinates.

I'm trying to create a function that can figure out which way to go, that should return a single element from that list.

That return value will be the direction the character moves.

*(Example: adjoining = [[1, 0], [3, 2], [1, 1]]. Return returns the smallest both x and y coordinate which is [1, 0].)*

**My function should return the value with the lowest x coordinate. If there are multiple x coordinates that have the same low value, the one with the lowest y coordinate should be chosen.**

How can I create a function that can figure out which x and y value is lowest?

Comment: You could use [min](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
minimum = min(adjoining, key=lambda elem: (elem[0], elem[1]))
```

Result:

```
[1, 0]
```

Use the `key` parameter to define the fields which will affect the sorting process. First, you will get the minimum element based on `x` value and if there are many of them, they will be sorted again based on their `y` value.

An alternative is to use the `itemgetter` function from `operator` module:

```
import operator

adjoining = [[1, 0], [3, 2], [1, 1]]

minimum = min(adjoining, key=operator.itemgetter(0,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use min() like so:

```
>>> adjoining = [[3,2],[1,1],[1,0]]
>>> min(adjoining)
[1, 0]
```

Comment: @SigurdSetså, Can you explain your logic more clearly [as an edit to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53241552/edit). Your question seems to imply `[0, 1]` comes before `[1, 0]`, i.e. `My function should return the value with the lowest x coordinate`. Concrete examples (rather than descriptions) often help.

Comment: @jpp I realised that my comment got it backwards. [0, 1] would be correct. I meant to say it the other way

Answer (score 0):

```
adjoining.sort(key= lambda x:x[0])
mins = [i for i in adjoining if i[0] == adjoining[0][0]]
if len(mins)>1:
   mins.sort(key= lambda x:x[1])
   min = [i for i in mins if i[1] == mins[0][1]]
else:
   min = mins
answer = min[0]
```

I used `sort` with the `key` attribute. This allows you to define the criteria by which to sort the list.
The rest of the code is base on list comprehension.

```
[ item for item in a list_of_items if item == wanted_item]
```

This filters `list_of_item` based of some chosen criteria. Just need to make sure what follows `if` can be evaluated `True` or `False`.

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.